# Can jQuery get an attribute from a HTML tag as string variable

Tags: jquery

I have a string of HTML tags and i want to retrieve all the attribute named 'name'. What should i do?

```
<input type="radio" name="read"/>

<input type="radio" name="write"/>

<input type="radio" name="speak"/>
```

I want to get read, write and speak.

Comment: See `.attr()` or `.prop()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `each` if you have multiple elements on the page:

```
$('input').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var string = '<input type="radio" name="read"/><input type="radio" name="write"/><input type="radio" name="speak"/>';
    getStringname(string);
});


function getStringname(string){
    $('body').append('<div id="createdDivforinput" style="display:none;">'+string+'</div>');
    $('#createdDivforinput input').each(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('name'));
    });
    $('#createdDivforinput').remove();
}
```

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ecev23gz/3/)